# How to remove extra vertical space in a table cell bordering makecell

Tags: vertical-alignment, makecell

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{ l  X }
  \hline
  \makecell[l]{Supplier\\(Executor):} & text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

How to get rid of the extra vertical space?

Comment: Use `\makecell[tl]{...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\makecell[tl]{...}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[t]{ l  X }
  \hline
  \makecell[tl]{Supplier\\(Executor):} & text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text\\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]